# Log out from new window separately than parent window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net application. This application opens a new window using javascript. this new window has a button which logs user out. but when a user is logged out from popup, She is logged out from main app as well. I am using forms authentication. How can I logout from parent application separately than the new window ? Both new popup page and parent popup uses same web.config.

logout function simply does this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this.  `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` will delete the forms authentication cookie on the client, which logs the user out of the main page too.

Comment: Can I use two cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

You could reload the parent page using javascript after completing the server side request which is removing the forms authentication cookie:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

> window.parent.location.reload();